# How to remove a substring in java

Tags: java, android, string, str-replace

I am receiving a file path with "xyz" appended to it. name would look like D:/sdcard/filename.docxyz

i am using the below code to remove  xyz but it is not working. what is missing here ?

```
    String fileExtension = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".")+1);

    String newExtension= fileExtension;

    newExtension.replace("xyz", "");

    path.replace(fileExtension, newExtension);

    return path;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is missing is that you need to save the result of your operations. Strings are *immutable* in Java, and the results of all `String` manipulations are therefore returned in the form of a new `String`:

```
newExtension = newExtension.replace("xyz", "");
path = path.replace(fileExtension, newExtension);
```

Answer (score 5):

`String` in java are immutable, and changes upon it never occurs in place, but every time a new string is returned,

```
newExtension  = newExtension.replace("xyz", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use replaceAll() with a regex.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "D:/sdcard/filename.docxyz";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("xyz$", "")); // $ checks only the end

}
```

O/P :

```
 input : s = "D:/sdcard/filename.docxyz";
 D:/sdcard/filename.doc 


 input : String s = "D:/sdcard/filenamexyz.docxyz";
 output : D:/sdcard/filenamexyz.doc
```

Comment: @Djon - This removes the trailing xyz.. Isn't this what the OP wants?

Comment: The question was about the code not working, look at the other answers to see why it did not.

Answer (score 0):

```
newExtension.replace("xyz", "");
```

Will only return string which has "xyz" removed but newExtension will remain as it is. Simple fix for your problem is use as below

```
String newExtension= fileExtension.replace("xyz", "");
```